# Not able to create a gradle project in the IntelliJ Idea IDE

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Everything I've looked up about this issue has stated that all I need to do is click on the "Create Gradle Project" button, but I do not have that and am not sure why it is not there. I have the most current version of intellij so I feel like everything should be there. I attached a photo so you can see what my screen looks like when I create a new project. To clarify, I have the gradle plugin enabled so that's why I'm so confused.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTvZ6.png)

Comment: Make sure Gradle plug-in is enabled: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html.

Comment: Reinstall the IDE from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. Perform the steps from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559.

Comment: I recommend using jetbrains toolbox to reinstall intellij, but still follow the article crazycoder linked.